# Can Bash autocd & tab-complete ignore specific folder in $PATH?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I recently moved from tcsh to bash, and have been adjusting to the different tab completions.

I use `shopt -s autocd` so I don't need to explicitly type cd in front of things, which is where the problem lies.

The only problem I have is that in my PATH is `/usr/local/bin/`, and inside that folder is an executable called `This.Is.A.Really.Long.File.To.Execute`.

Unfortunately, the git structure I use has the paths `~/git/company/This.Is/This.Is.A.Really.Long/This.Is.A.Really.Long.File/file.txt`

So if I am in `~/git/company/This.Is` and type `This.I<TAB>` it immediately completes to `This.Is.A.Really.Long.File.To.Execute`, which is the executable in my PATH.

I can't change the folder structure or move the executable because other processes/scripts use it. Is there a way to keep `autocd` and specifically ignore anything in  `/usr/local/bin/` from tab-completing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force Bash to only look in the current directory, you could always type:

```
./This.I<TAB>
```

Then again it's probably easier to just type `cd`.

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't be that, but I guess those 2 are my only options. I tried `FIGNORE=".Execute:~"` but I guess that isn't applicable to my problem.